# How to override a driver and program on a keypad

Tags: linux, windows, numeric-keypad

I'm trying to reprogram an external numeric keypad and I was wondering how I could override the device driver and original programming it was given. This would be for hopefully a Windows device but if I couldn't do that, then possibly a linux device.  I want to create my own driver and program and then make that the main software it will use.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Just uninstall it in the device manager?